# How to use named parameters with getHibernateTemplate()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to integrate Hibernate with Spring.

And this method works:

```
@Override
public Animal get(long id) {
    List list = getHibernateTemplate().find("from Animal where id=?", id);
    return (Animal) list.get(0);
}
```

But I have a

> WARN: [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter...

So, positional parameter are considered deprecated; I must use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.

How can I do this with "getHibernateTemplate()"?

Comment: use an older hibernate version where it is not yet deprecated.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245625/spring-hibernate-template-list-as-a-parameter It shows how to create a named parameter query, set its values and execute it

Comment: Don't use `HibernateTemplate`? The use of that has been discouraged since Hibernate 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

To use named parameters, you should use [findByNamedParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateOperations.html#findByNamedParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.Object:A-), this one also works:

```
@Override
public Animal get(long id) {
    List list = this.getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam("from Animal where id=:id", "id", id); 
    return (Animal) list.get(0);
}
```

List findByNamedParam(String queryString,
                         String[] paramNames,
                         Object[] values)
                  throws DataAccessException

Execute an HQL query, binding a number of values to ":" named parameters in the query string.

Parameters:

**queryString** - a query expressed in Hibernate's query language

**paramNames** - the names of the parameters

**values** - the values of the parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
@Override
public Animal get(long id) {
    String query = "from Animal where id=:id"
    List list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(query, "id", id);
    return (Animal) list.get(0);
}
```